# Dynamically allocate memory for storage of HTML source downloaded with WinHttpReadData

Tags: c++, memory-management, winhttp

First of all, string **cannot** be used, this is a requirement.

I am attempting to implement Winhttp in order to download content from HTTP. I have used the example provided on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384270(v=vs.85).aspx).

As im sure some of you are aware WinHttpReadData() reads data into a temp buffer, over writing existing data until the request is completed. This is fine if you simply want to print out the  buffer each time, however, i need to store the **entire** response into a buffer for use later.

For this i have created a struct which contains all the "things" i need to perform the request, i pass this struct by reference to the function which performs the request.
The struct is as follows:

```
struct HttpG
{
    wchar_t*    wszUserAgent; 
    wchar_t*    wszCookie;
    wchar_t*    wszHost;
    wchar_t*    wszPath; 
    char*       szResponse;
};
```

The function that does the request is defined as the following:

```
int HttpGet(HttpG &http_get);
```

So far so good....

Now the problem arises when i try to allocate memory dynamically for http_get.szResponse.
Not all data is getting read. I'm not going to post the entire example code from MSDN, but i will post the part of the code that is giving me the issue. If you look at the MSDN link above you will see which part of the code i am referring to. This is the main loop that downloads the data.

```
// Read the Data.
ZeroMemory(szOutBuffer, dwSize + 1);

if(!WinHttpReadData(hRequest, (LPVOID)szOutBuffer, dwSize, &dwDownloaded))
{                                  
    OutputDebugStr("Error in WinHttpReadData\n");   
}
else
{
     // Read data here              
     if(http_get.szResponse == NULL)
     {                  
         // This part seems to work as needed
         http_get.szResponse = new char[dwSize + 1];        
         ZeroMemory(http_get.szResponse, dwSize + 1);
         strcpy(http_get.szResponse, szOutBuffer);
         http_get.szResponse[dwSize + 1] = '\0';            
     }              
     else
     {
         // Im sure the problems is here, full source
         // is not getting put into http_get.szResponse.

         // Create temp buffer
         szTemp = new char[strlen(http_get.szResponse) + 1];    
         ZeroMemory(szTemp, strlen(http_get.szResponse) + 1);
         strcat(szTemp, http_get.szResponse);                   

         // Resize origonal buffer to hold new data                 
         http_get.szResponse = new char[strlen(szTemp) + dwSize + 1];
         ZeroMemory(http_get.szResponse, strlen(szTemp) + dwSize + 1);
         strcpy(http_get.szResponse, szTemp);
         strcat(http_get.szResponse, szOutBuffer);
         http_get.szResponse[strlen(szTemp) + dwSize + 1] = '\0';               
     }              
}           

// Free the memory allocated to the buffer.
delete[] szTemp;
delete[] szOutBuffer;           

// This condition should never be reached since WinHttpQueryDataAvailable
// reported that there are bits to read.
if(!dwDownloaded)
{
    break;
}
```

I create the struct and call function like this:

```
HttpG http_get;
http_get.wszHost = L"au.yahoo.com";
http_get.wszPath = L"/?p=us";
http_get.wszUserAgent = L"Blah blah blah";
http_get.szResponse = NULL;

HttpGet(http_get);
```

So essentially at the end of the request i want **all** the data to be inside http_get.szResponse. Sorry if this is a bit messy/vague, i tried to explain it as best as possible. What am i doing wrong?
Have been stuck on this all day, any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks guys.

Comment: I always get suspicious with "requirements" like "string cannot be used". That's sufficient reason to close any memory-related bug reports as "By Design".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call `WinHttpReadData()` in a loop until there is no more data to read, and you need to dynamically (re)allocate your response buffer on each iteration of that loop.  If the requirements forbid you from using `std::string` then they likely forbid you from using `std::vector` as well, so you will have to resort to manual memory management, eg:

```
struct HttpG
{
    wchar_t*    wszUserAgent; 
    wchar_t*    wszCookie;
    wchar_t*    wszHost;
    wchar_t*    wszPath; 
    u_char*     ucResponse;
    int         ucResponseSize;
};
```

```
u_char ucBuffer[1024], *ucTemp;    
DWORD dwDownloaded;

do
{
    if (!WinHttpReadData(hRequest, ucBuffer, sizeof(ucBuffer), &dwDownloaded))
    {                                  
        OutputDebugStr("Error in WinHttpReadData\n");   
        break;
    }

    if (dwDownloaded == 0)
        break;

    if (http_get.ucResponse == NULL)
    {                  
        http_get.ucResponse = new u_char[dwDownloaded];        
        memcpy(http_get.ucResponse, ucBuffer, dwDownloaded);
        http_get.ucResponseSize = dwDownloaded;            
    }              
    else
    {
        ucTemp = new u_char[http_get.ucResponseSize + dwDownloaded];    
        memcpy(ucTemp, http_get.ucResponse, http_get.ucResponseSize);                   
        memcpy(&ucTemp[http_get.ucResponseSize], ucBuffer, dwDownloaded);                   

        delete[] http_get.ucResponse;
        http_get.ucResponse = ucTemp;               
        http_get.ucResponseSize += dwDownloaded;
    }              
}
while (true);
```

```
HttpG http_get;
http_get.wszHost = L"au.yahoo.com";
http_get.wszPath = L"/?p=us";
http_get.wszUserAgent = L"Blah blah blah";
http_get.ucResponse = NULL;
http_get.ucResponseSize = 0;

HttpGet(http_get);

// use ucResponse up to ucResponseSize bytes as needed...

delete[] http_get.ucResponse;
```

Comment: So pro, it worked like a charm, i now have a better understanding of memory allocation. I also discovered another irritating thing which lead to me making this post (perhaps a blessing in disguise).

Originally i was using OutputDebugString() to output http_get.ucResponse this output was being truncated, i thought it was an error in my code, which lead to me making this post.

I noticed that even with your code it was doing it. So i wrote the contents of http_get.ucResponse to a file, boom, all data was there. So OutputDebugString was truncating http_get.ucResponse.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, i am curious, why did you use u_char over char?

Comment: `OutputDebugString()` takes null-terminated text as input. If the data being logged contains an embedded null byte, it will be treated as a null terminator and the logged data will be truncated. Remember that HTTP can transfer binary data, not just text data, so it is better to use `unsigned char` (or `u_char`, `BYTE`, `uint8_t`, etc - whatever you want to use for handling 8-bit binary data) to receive the raw HTTP data, and then interpret that data afterwards as needed, based on the HTTP `Content-Type` header.

Comment: I thought that might of been the issue with OutputDebugString(). Pretty sure you are not suppose to put null chars in HTML, either way i learnt a lot this morning. Thanks again for your help, i am now 1 step closer to being a C ninja. Have a great day.

Comment: It all depends on the charset of the HTML. If it were UTF-16, for instance, then there will be a LOT of null bytes. But most HTML is either UTF-8 or other 8bit charset that does not use nulls. Hard to say for sure what is happening to your log messages without seeing the actual data you are trying to log.

Comment: I see. Thanks again, you're a great help. This site is amazing.

Comment: Also, just a quick additiin. I noticed downloaded data sometimes has funky chars at the end, i would presume from non zero memory. I added a null terminator at the end and it displayed fine. If it were not text data and a file insread would it be best to use a byte array to store the files data instead. Eg. Mp3 or some image, non text data.

Comment: @SnakeByte: If you are getting garbage at the end then you are likely not managing the data buffers correctly, such as if you are not paying attention to the downloaded data size correctly. `WinHttpReadData()` should not be giving you garbage, unless the server is actually sending you garbage. You can use a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark or Fiddler, to verify that. But either way, you should always download data as a byte array first, and then interpret the bytes as needed based on the reported `Content-Type`.

Answer (score 0):

Even the code you believe is correct, isn't. You're assuming `szOutBuffer` is null-terminated. Read the documentation: that `&dwDownloaded` parameter is there for a reason.

In the "wrong" code, you of course have the same bug. In addition, you leak the old `szResponse` (precisely because you're not using a string class).

You then make the situation worse by moving string bits around in some completely wrong way. It seems you **append** the old response to the empty string `szTemp` (why? WHY?), copy it back into the newly allocated `szResponse`, and then append the (still incorrectly sized) `szOutBuffer`.

Finally, you write a `\0` outside `szResponse[]`

Style issue: you're [incorrectly assuming](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) `strlen` is free or at least O(1).

This code is a textbook example why people should use `std::string`. I would strongly advise you NOT to fix it. A rewrite using strings is the only reasonable action.

Comment: I wouldn't say a rewrite using std::string is the *only* reasonable action.  People have been working with strings in C since long before C++ and std::string even existed...

Comment: Thank you for the tip and taking the time to reply. The whole idea of this exercise was for me to learn memory allocation/strings the hard way, once i understand it i can use string. I feel that string adds bloat to the exe. Up voting for effort.

Comment: @SnakeByte: You have to do the allocations and deallocations anyway. Concentrating them into a few methods is usually a saving - putting manual allocations everywhere is the bloated solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `WinHttpReadData in a loop, and memcpy the downloaded data to another buffer to hold it all until you've retrieved the entire response.  Keep a pointer to the end of the buffer each time you copy into it.

Something like this (greatly oversimplified, showing only the basic structure of the loop):

```
char *myBuffer = malloc(bufSize);
char *bufPtr = myBuffer;
int totalBytes = 0;
while (!done)
{
    if (WinHttpReadData(hRequest, (LPVOID)outBuffer, dwSize, &dwDownloaded))
    {
        // if nothing left to download, we're done
        if (dwDownloaded == 0)
            done = true;
        else
        {
            // Might need to realloc() myBuffer here if you're going to pass the end of it
            if (myBuffer + totalBytes + dwDownloaded > bufSize);
                myBuffer = (char *)realloc(myBuffer, totalBytes + dwDownloaded);

            memcpy(bufPtr, outBuffer, dwDownloaded);
            bufPtr += dwDownloaded;
            totalBytes += dwDownloaded;
        }
    }
}

// Null terminate it so you can treat it like a C string.
*bufPtr = '\0';

// Now myBuffer contains the entire downloaded response as a null-terminated string.  Do whatever you want with it.
// Don't forget to free(myBuffer) when you're done with it.
```

Note:  This is not intended to be a working code example, and may contain bugs or even syntax errors (I haven't tested or even compiled it).  It is only intended to show the basic structure of a loop to accomplish what the asker is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply and help me. I was aware that i had to loop until no data was left, that was kind of obvious. Isn't it bad to use malloc / realloc in c++ (i guess the same argument could apply to not using string)? 
Up voting for effort.

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming C, not C++ (didn't notice the c++ tag in your question).  Yes, in C++ use new and delete instead of malloc() and free().